# .Net core fault-tolerant configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have .net core mvc applications. And I have configurations that customers want to change themselves through Consul (service discovery). They are afraid to make an error and prefer that apps fallback to a default value rather than stop working.

I know best practice is to throw an exception to fix it up faster. But those configs does not worth an unavailable app. Here is a bit simplified code:

```
    public class GreetingOptions
    {
        [Required, MinLength(10)]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required, Range(7, 20)]
        public int FontSize { get; set; }
    }
```

So far I found two options: put some defaults into `Configure()` (only works for nulls though) or handle exception every time:

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions<GreetingOptions>()
        .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("Greeting"))
        .Configure(options =>
        {
            options.Text ??= "Hello there!";
        })
        .ValidateDataAnnotations();
}

...

// inside some class
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly IOptionsMonitor<GreetingOptions> _optionsMonitor;

private GreetingOptions GetConfigSafe()
{
    try
    {
        return _optionsMonitor.CurrentValue;
    }
    catch (OptionsValidationException e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Configuration error");

        return new GreetingOptions
        {
            Text = "Hello dear friend",
            FontSize = 12,
        };
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to set up a fault-tolerant configuration that will log error and fallback to a given value? Can I somehow register IOptionsMonitor with such behavior?

*Update:*
By "fault" I mean misspelled properties or values that do not pass validation. For the above example this JSON config will fail:

```
"Greeting": {
    "Texxt": "Hello dear friend", // Text will be null
    "FontSize": 1 // Out of range
}
```

Comment: Will the configuration always be syntactically valid?

Comment: Probably not, but in that case I receive null values from Consul

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a minimal, reproducible example of a "fault" that you're trying to handle?

Comment: @devNull, I've added an example